# Use of LAG - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, lag

I need to calculate a column (`Transparencia`) as the sum of the previous row's `Transparencia` and `Dif` values. Initially, only the first row has a value in the `Transparencia` column:

```
    Account  ------ Year_ ---- Month_ ---- Transparencia ---- Dif 
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    '4030003'------ 2018 ----   5   ----     100       ---- -2  
    '4040001'------ 2018 ----   5   ----     null      ---- -4  
    '4040002'------ 2018 ----   5   ----     null      ----  3  
    ...
 Account(N-1)------ 2018 ----   5   ----       x        ----   8  
   Account(N)------ 2018 ----   5   ----     x + 8      ----  11
```

The aim is to get the following:

```
    Account  ------ Year_ ---- Month_ ---- Transparencia ---- Dif 
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    '4030003'------ 2018 ----   5   ----     100        ----  -2  
    '4040001'------ 2018 ----   5   ----      98        ----  -4  
    '4040002'------ 2018 ----   5   ----      94        ----   3  
    ...
 Account(N-1)------ 2018 ----   5   ----       x        ----   8  
   Account(N)------ 2018 ----   5   ----     x + 8      ----  11
```

Where:

- 98 = 100 + (-2) -> (`Transparencia` from previous row plus `Dif` from previous row)
- 94 = 98 + (-4) -> (`Transparencia` from previous row plus `Dif` from previous row)
- x = 'Transparencia' from the previos row + 'Dif' from the previous row
- x + 8 = 'Transparencia' from the previos row + 8 ('Dif' from the previous row)

The solution I tried was:

```
select
    tmp.Account, tmp.Year_, tmp.Month_,Dif,
    case 
       when Transparencia is null 
          then (lag(Transparencia, 1, 0) over (order by Account) - 
                lag(Dif, 1, 0) over (order by Account)) 
          else Transparencia 
    end Transparencia
from 
    (select
         Account, 
         nryear as Year_, nrperiod as Month_,
         Dif, Transparencia
     from 
         repaca 
     where 
         nrperiod = 5) tmp
```

However, this returns the following result:

```
Account  ------ Year_ ---- Month_ ---- Transparencia ----  Dif 
'4030003'------ 2018 ----   5   ----     100       ----  -2  
'4040001'------ 2018 ----   5   ----      98       ----  -4  
'4040002'------ 2018 ----   5   ----    null       ----   3
```

I need to achieve this using just a `SELECT`, not a stored procedure or alike. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `lag()`.  You want cumulative sum.  Because the value is `NULL`, you can simplify getting the first value by using `max()`.  So:

```
select r.*,
       (max(Transparencia) over () +
        sum(diff) over (order by year, month)
       ) as new_Transparencia
from repaca r;
```

You could also phrase this as:

```
select r.*,
       sum(coalesce(Transparencia, 0) + diff) over (order by year, month) as new_Transparencia
from repaca r;
```

EDIT:

The above is using the wrong ordering.  This seems to be:

```
select r.*,
       (max(Transparencia) over (partition by year, month) +
        sum(diff) over (partition by year, month order by account)
       ) as new_Transparencia
from repaca r;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but your code sums up Initial Transparencia with all diffs over year and period, but I just need Transparencia to be equals the previous 'Transparencia' + previous row's Diff (only one row previous). That's why I used LAG, to access only one previous row information.

Comment: @Andrew8902 . . . I misunderstood the data the first time.  You do want a cumulative sum, but it needs to use the right columns.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but I am still not getting what I need as a result. In my example, the rule of taking previous Transparencia + previous Diff applies only for the row n where n > 1. For the first row, I need just inicial Transparencia.